# Drools kie-ci example fails in ubber jar but not on eclipse IDE

Tags: maven, jar, drools, kie, maven-shade-plugin

I've been trying drools for a week now, and I was trying to build a small application that gets a kjar from the local maven repository. If I run my app in eclipse, everything works fine. If build an ubber jar with maven-shade-plugin and run java -jar myapp.jar the application fails with the exception provided in the attachments, despite adequately reading the kjar artifact from the local maven repository (I checked it by providing a non-existing artifact and it gave a proper error).

I searched for almost a day now, and wasn't able to find an explanation in drools documentation, in the provided examples on github or any other page indexed by Google :-/ I don't know if it is something related to the ubber jar, as all the examples do not mention how they deploy the application. Please help me!

I'm attaching part of the stack trace with the exception and my pom.xml. I did not changed any settings.xml related to Maven since the app seems to retrieve information from the local repo correctly.

**Stack trace**

```
0 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Loading kie.conf from
3 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Discovered kie.conf url=jar:file:/C:/Users/ccosta/git/myproject/rulesengine/target/rulesengine-0.0.1-shade.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf
65 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl

68 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl

78 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl

79 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl

81 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl

91 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.MarshallerProviderImpl

93 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl

101 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver

116 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl

117 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl

126 [main] INFO org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl  - Adding Service org.kie.scanner.KieScannerFactoryServiceImpl

141 [main] DEBUG org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl  - KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId org.lid4.myproject:rules:0.0.1 was not in cache, checking classpath
142 [main] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl  - Adding KieModule from classpath: file:/C:/Users/ccosta/git/myproject/rulesengine/target/rulesengine-0.0.1-shade.jar
148 [main] DEBUG org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject  - KieModule URL type=jar url=/C:/Users/ccosta/git/myproject/rulesengine/target/rulesengine-0.0.1-shade.jar
410 [main] DEBUG org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject  - Found and used pom.properties META-INF/maven/org.lid4.myproject/rulesengine/pom.properties
1057 [main] WARN org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenSettings  - Environment variable M2_HOME is not set
1093 [main] DEBUG org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils  - Not in OSGi: using plexus based maven parser
1489 [main] ERROR org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder  - Unable to build MavenEmbedder
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:134)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:96)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:87)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:92)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:76)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:70)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
        at org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getPomModel(AbstractKieModule.java:378)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getJarDependencies(AbstractKieModule.java:130)
        at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:66)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule.createModuleClassLoader(InternalKieModule.java:137)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:56)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:191)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
        at org.lid4.myproject.rulesengine.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        ... 20 more
1492 [main] ERROR org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader  - Unable to create new MavenEmbedder
org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:108)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:87)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:92)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:76)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:70)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
        at org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getPomModel(AbstractKieModule.java:378)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getJarDependencies(AbstractKieModule.java:130)
        at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:66)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule.createModuleClassLoader(InternalKieModule.java:137)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:56)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:191)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
        at org.lid4.myproject.rulesengine.App.main(App.java:22)



... More of the same (removed to fulfil stackoverlow char limits)...




1520 [main] DEBUG org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils  - Not in OSGi: using plexus based maven parser
1581 [main] ERROR org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder  - Unable to build MavenEmbedder
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:134)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:96)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:87)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:56)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.loadMavenProject(MavenProjectLoader.java:121)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.Aether.getAether(Aether.java:75)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository.getMavenRepository(MavenRepository.java:95)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.ArtifactResolver.<init>(ArtifactResolver.java:52)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.ArtifactResolver.getResolverFor(ArtifactResolver.java:146)
        at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:72)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule.createModuleClassLoader(InternalKieModule.java:137)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:56)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:191)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
        at org.lid4.myproject.rulesengine.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        ... 19 more
1582 [main] WARN org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader  - Unable to parse pom.xml file of the running project: org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
1657 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider  - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\ccosta\.m2\repository
1661 [main] DEBUG org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils  - Not in OSGi: using plexus based maven parser
1716 [main] ERROR org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder  - Unable to build MavenEmbedder
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:134)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:96)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:87)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:56)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.loadMavenProject(MavenProjectLoader.java:121)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.loadMavenProject(MavenProjectLoader.java:114)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.EmbeddedPomParser.<init>(EmbeddedPomParser.java:32)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.ArtifactResolver.<init>(ArtifactResolver.java:53)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.ArtifactResolver.getResolverFor(ArtifactResolver.java:146)
        at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:72)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule.createModuleClassLoader(InternalKieModule.java:137)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:56)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:191)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
        at org.lid4.myproject.rulesengine.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        ... 19 more
1716 [main] WARN org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader  - Unable to parse pom.xml file of the running project: org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.lid4.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.lid4.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>rulesengine</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>rulesengine</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lid4.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>rules</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>org.lid4.myproject.rulesengine.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.lid4.myproject.rulesengine.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Java Code**

```
package org.lid4.intelligentdatabroker.rulesengine;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.drools.core.util.Drools;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.lid4.intelligentdatabroker.rules.Measurement;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        ks.newReleaseId("org.lid4.myproject", "rules", "0.0.1");
        ks.newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId("org.lid4.myproject", "rules", "0.0.1"));

        // Install example1 in the local maven repo before to do this
        //KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId("org.lid4.myproject", "rules", "0.0.1"));

        //KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
        //kSession.setGlobal("out", System.out);

        Measurement m1 = new Measurement("1", "1");
        //kSession.insert(m1);
        //kSession.fireAllRules();
    }
}
```

**----------Edit-----------**

Now it fails with

```
1641 [main] ERROR org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder  - Unable to build MavenEmbedder
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuilder
  roleHint:
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:235)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:134)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:96)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:87)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:56)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.loadMavenProject(MavenProjectLoader.java:121)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.Aether.getAether(Aether.java:75)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository.getMavenRepository(MavenRepository.java:95)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.ArtifactResolver.<init>(ArtifactResolver.java:52)
        at org.appformer.maven.integration.ArtifactResolver.getResolverFor(ArtifactResolver.java:146)
        at org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver.getClassLoader(MavenClassLoaderResolver.java:72)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule.createModuleClassLoader(InternalKieModule.java:137)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieModuleKieProject.<init>(KieModuleKieProject.java:56)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:191)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
        at org.lid4.intelligentdatabroker.rulesengine.App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        ... 20 more
```

After adding this configuration to the maven-shade-plugin. So I'm suspecting it really is a maven-shade-plugin related problem, but I don't know another way of building an ubber jar to use Drools in an application.

```
<transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">                                  
                                        <resource>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</resource>                                   
                                </transformer>
```

Thanks in advance,
Carlos Costa

Answer (score 3):

We got Drools running from an uber-JAR with the following configuration for the maven-shade-plugin.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <!-- some transformers omitted -->
            <transformer
              implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer" />
            <transformer
              implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer
              implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named</resource>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

It just differs from your solution in the addition of the 'org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ComponentsXmlResourceTransformer' transformer. Hope it helps.

Best regards!

Comment: This was really helpful. I was able to use this and finally was able to get my AWS lambda setup with Drools 7.19.0.Final working.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just my 2 cents, because what you're trying to do is way over my head at the moment.

But I did see in your stacktrace
'1057 [main] WARN org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenSettings  - Environment variable M2_HOME is not set'

1. (Win7) Control Panel/System/Advanced System Settings -> System Properties Pop Up/Tab Advanced/Button 'Environment Variables' ->Environment Variables Pop Up, Bottom Window 'System Variables'.
2. Make sure you have both an M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME entry there pointing to your maven install; edit or add if necessary.

It COULD be the reason your MavenEmbedder fails to build.